# LINQ problem: FK-Table not set correctly

Tags: asp.net, database, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 3 Tables.

Guilds, Kills, Faction.

1 Guild = x Kills, 1 Guild = X Factions.

All FK are correctly set in database.

Now, when I try to do a Query like "from a in dc.guilds where a.kills.Killd = X select a" it is not possible, because the table kills is not set as "kills", it is set as "EntitySet(Kills)".

http://s3.imgimg.de/uploads/1624074f5png.png

When I try to do the same with the faction, it forks.

Whats my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
where a.kills.Any(k => k.KillId == X)
```